# Indexing finite subsets

Tags: combinatorics, index-notation

Let $X\triangleq\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set of $n$ vectors $x_1, \dots, x_n \in\mathbb{R}^d$. I'm trying to formalize how to index all possible subsets $Y\subseteq X$ because I have to compute a summation in the following form
\begin{equation*}S(X)\triangleq\sum_{Y\subseteq X} f(Y)\end{equation*}
where $f$ is a set function $f:\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^d)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, with $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ being the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
In order to fix the ideas we can consider
\begin{equation*}
f(\{x_1,\dots,x_n\})=\begin{cases}
\quad\hfil 0     & \text{ if } n=0 \\
\quad\hfil \prod_{i=1}^n \lVert x_i \rVert & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
there is nothing special in this function, it is just a random example.

**toy example**

Let $n\triangleq3$, so that $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$. In this case the possible cardinalities $c\triangleq|Y|$ of $Y$ are $c=0,1,2,3$. Then, listing in cardinality $c$ order, we have the following possible 8 subsets of $X$

- for $c=0$: $Y=\varnothing$
- for $c=1$: $Y=\{x_1\},\{x_2\}.\{x_3\}$
- for $c=2$: $Y=\{x_1,x_2\}, \{x_1,x_3\}, \{x_2,x_3\}$
- for $c=3$: $Y=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$

the idea to indicize the previous subsets $Y$ is the following: lets forget for the momement the empty case, then for a given cardinality $c\in\{1,2,3\}$, we have to pick up $c$ indexes $i_{1},\dots,i_c$ from the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Since we are defining a set $Y$, the $c$ indexes
must be constructed according to the following rules:

1. no repetitions, in the sense that $i_1\neq i_2 \neq \dots \neq i_c$
2. no permutations, in the sense that $i_1< i_2 < \dots < i_c$

Clearly, rule 2 absorb rule 1. Let's call the set of all possible indexes $i_{1},\dots i_c$ satisfying rule 2 as $P_{c,3}^{>}$. This set is given by
\begin{equation*}
P_{c,3}^{>}\triangleq \left\{\begin{array}{rl}
i_1&=1,2,3\\
i_2&=1,2,3\qquad i_2>i_1\\
\vdots&\\
i_c&=1,2,3\qquad i_c>i_{c-1}> \dots >i_1
\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation*}
we have (sorry for the different representation of the elements, I hope you get the point)
\begin{equation*}
P_{1,3}^{>}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
(i_1=1)\\
(i_1=2)\\
(i_1=3)
\end{array}\right\}
\qquad
P_{2,3}^{>}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
(i_1=1, i_2=2)\\
(i_1=1, i_2=3)\\
(i_1=2, i_2=3)
\end{array}\right\}
\qquad
P_{3,3}^{>}=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
(i_1=1, i_2=2, i_3=3)
\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation*}
accordingly, if I'm not wrong so far, we can write
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{Y\subseteq X} f(Y)= f(\varnothing)+\sum_{c=1}^{3} \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_c\in P_{c,3}^{>}} f(\{x_{i_{1}},\dots, x_{i_c}\})
\end{equation*}

Just for a quick check, the total number of terms in the summation is, as expected,
\begin{equation*}
1+\sum_{c=1}^3 |P_{c,3}^{>}|=1+\sum_{c=1}^{3} \binom{3}{c}=\sum_{c=0}^{3} \binom{3}{c}=2^3=8
\end{equation*}

**general case**

For an arbitrary set $X$ it should hold the following
\begin{equation*}
S(X) = f(\varnothing)+\sum_{c=1}^{|X|} \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_c \in P_{c,|X|}^{>}} f(\{x_{i_1},\dots, x_{i_c}\})
\end{equation*}
which should include $2^{|X|}$ terms because such number is
\begin{equation*}
1+\sum_{c=1}^{|X|} \binom{|X|}{c}=\sum_{c=0}^{|X|} \binom{|X|}{c}=2^{|X|}
\end{equation*}

**Question**

Does it makes sense my solution? Is it correct?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question/motivation, but note that there is a natural bijection between subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and elements of $\{0,1\}^n$, and the latter can be put into bijection with $\{0,\dots,2^n-1\}$ using binary.